# gwt: making remote calls fails - sop?

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, same-origin-policy

I am writing some interface for users to collect data and send to a server. I went for GWT for various reasons.

Now, when I try to call my server:

```
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/data/collection.xml";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(url));

Request request = builder.sendRequest(data, new RequestCallback() {     

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

              if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                  result.setText("SUCCESS!");
              } else {
                  result.setText("ERROR with code: " + response.getStatusCode());
```

My server gets the request (a POST with some data) but I get ERROR with code: 0 (!) all the time. I guess this has to do with SOP. I read lots about this SOP but I am even more confused now. I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=126) but that's using a different approach (I managed to adapt it to issue GET calls only, but return objects are always null).

Can anyone point me into the right direction? thanks

Comment: First install Firebug to monitor Firefox network connections and request and responses on browser and then have you read http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite.html#design ?

Comment: I believe you simply can't do it this way!

Comment: yep. my investigations revealed it only works if the destination sets the Allow-Origin-something HTTP header to *....JSONP is an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call any service from another server because of SOP. What you can do, you can use your original server as proxy to other servers.. I would recommend you to read [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/FAQ_Server#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?).